# Function to evaluate variables in BASH

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Given a variable name is there a function that will print its value?

Often times I pass the name of a variable to a bash function and instead of doing the expansion while passing it I would like to expand it inside the function. Of course when I do this I end up having to create the string with the variable name then running exec. It would be much more succinct if I could just run a command that echoed the output!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
show_val() { echo "${!1}"; }
foo=bar
echo $(show_val foo)   # => bar
# works with arrays too
a=(zero one two)
echo $(show_val a[1])  # => one
```

Documented in the bash manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: As always Ty for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean in your question about "running exec".  Perhaps you meant eval.

```
show_val() { eval echo \$$1; }
foo=bar
show_val foo
```